# How to display a banner top of a redirected page if the payment has been successful or unsuccessful

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have integrated my stripe client checkout. As you can see in the code, there is a section (successUrl and cancelUrl where it redirects the user (I have xxx it out). But I require one more thing to happen.

If the payment is successful, it will display a green banner on the redirected page with text 'Successful Payment' and the user can close the banner. If the payment was unsuccessful then it will do the same but it's a red banner and says 'Payment cancelled'.

How can this be implemented?

```
(function() {
  var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxP');

  var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button-sku_xxxxxxxxxx');
  checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    // When the customer clicks on the button, redirect
    // them to Checkout.
    stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      items: [{sku: 'sku_xxxxxxxx', quantity: 1}],

      // Do not rely on the redirect to the successUrl for fulfilling
      // purchases, customers may not always reach the success_url after
      // a successful payment.
      // Instead use one of the strategies described in
      // https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfillment
      successUrl: window.location.protocol + '//www.xxx-xxx.com/xxx/xx-xxx',
      cancelUrl: window.location.protocol + '//www.xxx-xxx.com/xxx/xx-xxx',
    })
    .then(function (result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
        // error, display the localized error message to your customer.
        var displayError = document.getElementById('error-message');
        displayError.textContent = result.error.message;
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Is page you redirecting to part of your project or some external website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect to a page with a parameter

```
www.xxx-xxx.com/xxx/xx-xxx?success=true
```

Then using javaScript on redirected page

```
let url = new URL(window.location.href);
let success = url.searchParams.get("success");
if(success) {
  document.getElementById('stripe-info').classList.add('visible')
}
```

Html

```
<div id="stripe-info">Stripe payment successful</div>
```

CSS

```
#stripe-info {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
   // then background color, width etc.
}
#stripe-info.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a parameter to url which you want redirect and read that parameter in destination page, then show proper banner based on url parameter.